Command Center / Dynamic Island missing icons and animations
I'm setting up a really simple media player in my swiftui app.
the code is the following:
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer

class AudioPlayerProvider {
    private var player: AVPlayer
    
    init() {
        self.player = AVPlayer()
        self.player.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false
        
        self.setupAudioSession()
        self.setupRemoteCommandCenter()
    }
    
    private func setupAudioSession() {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playback, mode: .default)
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to set up audio session: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
    private func setupRemoteCommandCenter() {
        let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()
        
        commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return .commandFailed }
            self.play()
            return .success
        }
        
        commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self = self else { return .commandFailed }
            self.pause()
            return .success
        }
    }
    
    func loadAudio(from urlString: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
        
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        
        self.player.pause()
        self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.streamFinished), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player.currentItem)
    }
    
    func setMetadata(title: String, artist: String, duration: Double) {
        var nowPlayingInfo = [
            MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: title,
            MPMediaItemPropertyArtist: artist,
            MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration: duration,
            MPNowPlayingInfoPropertyPlaybackRate: 1.0,
           
        ] as [String: Any]
        
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
    
    @objc
    private func streamFinished() {
        self.player.seek(to: .zero)
        
        try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)
        
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().playbackState = .stopped
    }
    
    func play() {
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().playbackState = .playing
            
        self.player.play()
    }
    
    func pause() {
        MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().playbackState = .paused
            
        self.player.pause()
    }
}

pretty scholastic.
The code works when called on views. It also shows up within the lock screen / dynamic island (when in background), but here lies the problems:

The play/pause button do not appear neither in the Command Center nor in the dynamic island. If I tap on the position these button should show up, the command works. Just the icons are not appearing.
the waveform animation does not animate when playing.

Many audio apps are working just fine so is my code lacking something. But I don't know why.
What is missing?

Well, in the end the problem is limited on the simulator. Working on a real device shows no issue
